# Android - GlSurfaceView in Fragment is running twice at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, opengl-es

I have an android app that uses a `GlSurfaceView` to render a 3D fullscreen scene inside a fragment. I have noticed in the profiler, that the `GlSurfaceView` is actually running **twice** (in two threads), hogging resources and tanking the FPS. I have confirmed the issue by rendering the same OpenGL scene (using the same `Renderer` implementation) to a live wallpaper and profiling it, which only runs it once.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

---

The code is as follows:

**MySurfaceView**

```
class MySurfaceView(ctx: Context): GLSurfaceView(ctx)
{
    init
    {
        setEGLContextClientVersion(3)
        preserveEGLContextOnPause = true
        setRenderer( /* instantiating the renderer class */ )
    }
}
```

**OpenGLFragment**

```
class OpenGLFragment: Fragment()
{
    private lateinit var glView: GLSurfaceView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        this.glView = MySurfaceView(this.activity)
        return this.glView
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fm = supportFragmentManager
        for (i in 0 until fm.getBackStackEntryCount()) {
            fm.popBackStack()
        }

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, OpenGLFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure for this line :  MySurfaceView(this.activity). , maybe new  MySurfaceView(this.activity) .

Comment: @nikola lukic this is kotlin, it has no `new`. The code is working besides the duplicate fragment problem.

Comment: What's in your layout? One possible cause is if your layout file already includes an `OpenGLFragment` and then you add a second one in `onCreate()`

Comment: Is it becuase you add `Fragment` to backstack *(May be possible cause)*? Just try replacing `Fragment` in `FragmentManager` instead.

Comment: @JeelVankhede How does this even work? Currently, every time I switch to another app and go back to this app, it is restarted. That is fine, but can I have fragments run in the back somehow?

Comment: hey @nshct i would like you to replace instead of add (that's to make sure you only have one fragment no matter what if that's the only fragment you are using in MainActivity) and let me know what behavior happens afterwards

Comment: If you don't add your `Fragment` to backstack may be it won't get two instances at a time and so that your `SurfaceView` won't get initialise twice.

Comment: Try removing .addToBackStack(null), you're adding your Fragment to backstack, maybe that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to add fragment instead of replacing the container.

Here is my code:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, GLFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

Fragment(using your code does not compile with `this.activity`)

```
class GLFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var glView: GLSurfaceView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        this.glView = MySurfaceView(requireActivity())
        return this.glView
    }
}
```

GLView:

```
class MySurfaceView constructor(context: Context) : GLSurfaceView(context) {
    init {
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2) // I have used 2 because running on emulator
        preserveEGLContextOnPause = true
        setRenderer(ClearRenderer())
    }
}

internal class ClearRenderer : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10?, config: EGLConfig?) {
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10, w: Int, h: Int) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    }
}
```

and here is profiler screenshot:

[image]

So to recapitulate replace the `add` with `replace`, replace the `this.activity` with `requireActivity()` the `requireActivity()` also does not return null and it is guaranteed.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Can you please stop providing this idi*tic Kotlin syntax which is not universal? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that you should check:

- You are only allowed to call `setRenderer` once in the lifecycle of the GLSurfaceView. See [GLSurfaceView.setRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderer(android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer)).
- Are you calling `glView.onPause()` and `glView.onResume()` to stop rendering, if the view is in background? See [GLSurfaceView life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView#activity-life-cycle).
- You should use `transaction.replace()` instead of `transaction.add()`. You may end up having multiple `OpenGlFragments` active at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. I guess me not using onPause etc is the reason the OpenGL state is always recreated when I switch the app to background and then back? How do I stop that from happening?